# Spring Security, OAuth and Pre-Authorization

Tags: java, spring, oauth, spring-security, restful-authentication

Can anyone provide some information, hints or tutorials that demonstrate how to use [Spring Security OAuth](http://spring-security-oauth.codehaus.org) with Spring's PreAuthorize feature? Ideally, I would like to link a username used for preauthorization to OAuth credentials.

Comment: Do you talk about Version 1.0 or 2.0?

Comment: Is this what you want? http://spring-security-oauth.codehaus.org/tutorial.html and http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/02/oauth-with-spring-security.html

Comment: Might this link help you:- 
http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/security/oauth/115232-oauth2-client-for-single-sign-on-and-pre-authenticaion

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33638850/