# How to protect spring-security-oauth resources using @PreAuthorize based on Scope?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security-oauth2

I successfully configured spring-security-oauth2 so that external apps can authenticate with my application. However based on the external app and based on what the user allows, only a subset of my API should be accessible to clients. The available subset is determined by the OAuth Scopes.

In classic Spring applications I could use @PreAuthorize to enforce boundaries based on roles:

```java
@Controller
public class MyController {
  @PreAuthorize("hasRole('admin')")
  @RequestMapping("...")
  public String doStuff() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

How do I do the same when using OAuth and with Scopes instead of roles?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Spring OAuth ships with the `OAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler`, a class that adds the ability to do such checks using the @PreAuthorize expressions. All you need to do is register this class, e.g. like this if you are using Javaconfig:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public static class MethodSecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {
    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
        return new OAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
    }
}
```

Now you can simply use:

```java
@PreAuthorize("#oauth2.hasScope('requiredScope')")
```

to secure your request methods. To see which further methods are available besided `hasScope` check the class `OAuth2SecurityExpressionMethods`.

The downside is that `OAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler` extends the `DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler` and thus you cannot combine it with other classes that also extend this class.

As an alternative you could also [map OAuth scopes to classic user roles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22417780/using-scopes-as-roles-in-spring-security-oauth2-provider).

Comment: I am using Spring Boot 1.5.10 and the `#oauth2.hasScope...` works without overriding `createExpressionHandler()`

Comment: Do you have any idea how I can unit test a function using @PreAuthorize("#oauth2.hasScope('requiredScope')")? I have sorted it out for other security 
criteria but I can't figure out this one.